# Unable to install device agent in iOS 13

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2019, xamarin.uitest

I tried to run xamarin ui test for iOS, it getting working on my iPhone iOS version 12.
When I tried it with iOS13 getting exception
Xamarin.UiTest.XDB.DeviceAgentException: Failed to install device agent.

I tried multiple xamarin ui test version none of them working.

Currently I am using
Xamarin.UiTest 3.0.7
Nunit 2.6.4
NunitTestAdapter 2.2.0

Comment: Have you tried the version 3.0.5?It seems this issue is fixed in the version,You could refer [github link](https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter/issues/829)

Comment: I tried all version 2.0.7 to 3.0.7 none of them help to install device agent.

Comment: I could not reproduce this,you could try to report it on github.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely a bug in the UITest Nuget package that seems to be recurring since v3.

Have you tried the newer version of the Nuget package: 3.0.8-dev1? It may only be available in the Alpha channel.

I would recommend going [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.UITest/) and tapping on "Contact Owners" to report the bug.

To verify that it's not just your issue, you could quite Visual Studio, delete all the bin and obj folders, delete the app from your phone and then try again (or just `git clean -fxd` if you have a .gitignore file)

Comment: I have tried these too but still its not working. Same uitest working on ios 12 device. But it's not installing device agent in ios13 device.

Comment: @tarunmittal are you using a Mac or are you using a Mac agent through your windows?

Comment: I am using mac machine.